# Displaying login error on same page when using a class (php)

Tags: php, ajax, oop, authentication

I have a form to login

```
    <div class="fade_bg">
        <div class="actionDiv">
            <form id="login_form" action="./classes/login/Authenticator.php" method="post">
                <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
                <p>password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="adminLogin" value="Log in" id="adminLogin" />
                    <input type="submit" name="cancelLogin" value="Cancel" id="cancelLogin" />      
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice the form action is './classes/login/Authenticator.php.' The PHP script is by itself with no HTML or anything.

What I want is for an error message to display inside

```
   <div class="actionDiv">
```

If the user enters an empty form or the wrong credentials. I've tried using AJAX, but it didn't work.

The login itself works. I just need to print the errors.

Here is the AJAX I used:

```
            $('#adminLogin').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax ({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: './classes/login/Authenticator.php',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == 'invalid credentials')
                            $('body').html(data);
                        else
                            $('.fade_bg').fadeOut(200);
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert('Invalid username or password');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Show your `$.ajax` code

Comment: What does this `The PHP script is by itself with not HTML or anything.` mean what you have written?

Comment: Sorry about that. Done.

Comment: I meant that I didn't embed the PHP in any HTML.

Comment: I know I could embed it and have the action be itself, but I wanted to keep my classes separate.

Comment: Do you want restrict Users at the time of filling form or you want to inform User whether they have sent blank form or invalid User Credentials? Means you don't want to validate form at client side? Or you just want to send form information on Server side and there you're checking form information and based on it you want to inform Users about it?

Comment: What's the name of the file containing the `<div class="actionDiv">`HTML? Is your AJAX in the PHP file?

Comment: Nullvoid, I want both.

Comment: Revent, it's index.php. My AJAX is in the footer include file

Answer (score 1):

The form is probably getting submitted by the browser. You can prevent the default action.

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //perform ajax request here. 
});
```

Comment: When I added this line, it disabled this:     $('a#aLogin').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.fade_bg').fadeIn(200);
     $('a#aLogin').hide();
    });

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the submit button from submitting the form:

```
$('#adminLogin').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();    
  ...
```

And if you want to display the return message in the `.actionDiv`, then do so in your ajax success callback:

```
if(data == 'invalid credentials')
  $('.actionDiv').append($('<p/>').text(data));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For client side validation you need to check before `$.ajax` call this condition

You have to also give `id` to both input fields

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#adminLogin').on('click',function() {
            //alert("hello");
            var name = $("#username").val();
            var error = 0 ;
            if(name == ""){
                $("#errUsername").fadeIn().text("Username required.");
                $("#username").focus();
                error++;
            }

            var password= $("#password").val();
            if(password== ""){
                $("#errPassword").fadeIn().text("Password required.");
                $("#password").focus();
                error++;
            }
            if(error > 0)
            {
                error = 0;
                $('.actionDiv').append($('<p/>').text('invalid credentials'));
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax ({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'login.php',
                //dataType: 'text',
                data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    if(data == 'invalid credentials')
                    {
                        $('.actionDiv').append($('<p/>').text(data));
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    alert('Invalid username or password');
                }
            });
        });
});
```

You need to add these two `<span>` tags near to `Username` and `Password` inputs respectively so that client side errors can be show in these two `spans`

Then on Server side When you check submitted form like

```
<?php

    $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
    $pswd = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "";

    //perform query operation whether Username with valid password is exist or not

    if($notExist)
        echo "invalid credentials";
    else
        echo "success";
?>
```

And when `$.ajax` response comes then you can inform user about `invalid credentials` in `success` like

```
if(data == 'invalid credentials')
  $('.actionDiv').append($('<p/>').html(data));
```

Comment: Ok this all makes sense, but when I added e.preventDefault(), it disabled something: $('a#aLogin').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $('.fade_bg').fadeIn(200); $('a#aLogin').hide(); });